# Can you parameterize UIElements using XAML at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-store-apps

Sorry for the poorly-worded title. Let me give an example to clarify what I'm asking. Let's say you created an application that allows the user to create a grid. The user gets to choose the size, say anywhere between a 2 x 2 to a 10 x 10. Programmatically it's straightforward to implement, but could you do the same using XAML without explicitly defining each grid separately? If it were possible, would it offer any advantages over the programmatic solution? Thanks.

Comment: An answer for windows store apps may not apply to wpf and vice versa, which are you dev'ing with?

Comment: You are right. I'm asking for windows store apps case. Thanks.

Comment: You could, but I think you'd need to create a control which updates a property, which I don't believe exists by default. You could then create a grid which binds its height or width to the value. If you were okay with just using a ViewModel to hold the value in the back-end, then you wouldn't need a custom control. You'd just need the setter control to use a two-way binding to the VM property and the Grid to use one-way binding.